# Is Jester word derogatory?

Tags: pejorative-language, offensive-language

Jester means professional fool. Fool is a bad word. Is Jester word derogatory?

Comment: Can you provide some context? Calling a comedian a jester might not be derogatory, calling a politician one probably is.

Comment: I'm editing my photo in Facebook with jester costume. And the caption is Jester. When i search the definition of Jester on Wikipedia, it says professional fool. Fool is a bad word, I think. Is it derogatory?

Comment: *Fool* is often derogatory, but it probably isn't in the phrase *professional fool*; *clown* can be derogatory, but not in the phrase *circus clown*. and *jester* could be used in a derogatory way, but not when attached to a photo of somebody in a jester costume.

Comment: You can post yourself in a jester suit and caption it *dignified*, but it won't make you dignified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not derogatory.

As well as being a word for a foolish person, *fool* in earlier times referred to a comedian employed by a monarch or other important person to make them laugh when they wanted to relax. Your jester costume would be an imitation of the kind of outfit such men wore (like the Joker in a pack of playing cards). Fool and jester are just names for the person's job.

Comment: That's jester opinion.